# Is 宵宮 considered 3 syllables or 4 syllables?

Tags: pronunciation

I think everyone can agree that 宵宮(よいみや) has 4 mora. But one side says it has 4 syllables because there are 4 vowels.

The other side says "Yoi" is similar to the かあ in 母さん and thus only have 3 syllables.
https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9F%B3%E7%AF%80#%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AE%E9%9F%B3%E7%AF%80

Which side is right here?

Comment: Which part of the linked article says /oi/ is similar to /aa/ or /ii/ when it comes to counting syllables?

Comment: Nowhere. The linked article says かあ is one syllable. One side contends (without evidence) that the "よい" situation is like the "かあ" situation .

Comment: Do you have any reference?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a public reference. This is just an online argument between two people. One guy alleges it's 3 syllables while the other guy alleges it's 4 syllables. I don't know which side is correct.

Comment: "Syllable" is an ambiguous word in Japanese studies. Some use syllable to tell the exact English concept of syllable, where other as a synonym of "mora" because the former "syllable" has little meaning in Standard Japanese. You have to check out how they define the word.

Comment: I see you are a Genshin Impact player...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[宵宮]{よいみや} takes four syllables.

I don’t know about the game(?) character, but as a normal word, it seems to be pronounced as よいみや{LHHH} according to [NHK’s accent dictionary](https://sakura-paris.org/dict/NHK%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E7%99%BA%E9%9F%B3%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E8%BE%9E%E5%85%B8/content/5624_1682).

The same word is also read as よみや{HLL}, and it can be written as 夜宮 in this case.

If it is a person’s last name, I would guess it is pronounced as よいみや{LHLL}.

The /oi/ sequence could sometimes sound like it constitutes one syllable (i.e. diphthong), as in よいこ{HLL}, but I think it is generally considered a combination of two syllables.